# Error while creating the folder in android using flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a folder in the internal storage of the mobile with some name. when I trying to create a folder i am getting an error like this
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/wizApp' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

this my dart code for folder creation

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

// void exportData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) async {
//   final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
//   print('Download directory: ${directory.path}'); // Print the directory path

//   final file = File('${directory.path}/data.json');
//   final jsonData = jsonEncode(data);
//   await file.writeAsString(jsonData);

//   print('Data exported successfully!');
// }

Future<bool> saveData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> data, String fileName) async {
  Directory directory;
  try {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
        directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String newPath = "";
        print(directory);
        List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
        for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
          String folder = paths[x];
          if (folder != "Android") {
            newPath += "/" + folder;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        newPath = newPath + "/wizApp";
        directory = Directory(newPath);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
        directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    File saveFile = File(directory.path + "/$fileName");
    if (!await directory.exists()) {
      await directory.create(recursive: true);
    }
    if (await directory.exists()) {
      final file = File('${directory.path}/data.json');
      final jsonData = jsonEncode(data);
      await file.writeAsString(jsonData);

      print('Data exported successfully!');
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(saveFile.path,
            isReturnPathOfIOS: true);
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return false;
  }
}

Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
  if (await permission.isGranted) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var result = await permission.request();
    if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This my manifest file settings

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blockly">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" /> -->
   <application
        android:label="Wizklub IoT App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
         
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified internal storage, is it the right info ? Because it seems you are trying to write on the external storage.

You can simply use this sample for internal storage writing:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class CreateFolder extends StatelessWidget {
  const CreateFolder({super.key});

  Future<String?> createNewFolder() async {
    try {
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final folderPath = '${directory.path}/MyFolder';

      final folder = Directory(folderPath);
      await folder.create(recursive: true);
      print("Folder created at: $folderPath");
      return folderPath;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating folder: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          createNewFolder();
        },
        child: Text("Create folder"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```